# Linux command to subprocess.getoutput() getting invalid syntax

Tags: python, linux

I have a command that pull a list of printer name along with its IP address:

```
lpstat -v | awk '{sub(":", "", $3) sub("ipp://", "", $4) sub("/ipp/print", "", $4); print $3 ", "  $4}'
PRINTER01, 192.168.25.200
PRINTER02, 192.168.24.200
...
```

I'm trying to pull that information into Python using `subprocess.getoutput()` like so:

```
printers = subprocess.getoutput("lpstat -v | awk '{sub(":", "", $3) sub("ipp://", "", $4) sub("/ipp/print", "", $4); print $3 ", "  $4}'")
```

However the above does not work and I can't seem to figure out the correct way to use the quotes....or maybe I need to escape the colon?

The error message I receive when running the above is:

```
    printers = subprocess.getoutput("lpstat -v | awk '{sub(":", "", $3) sub("ipp://", "", $4) sub("/ipp/print", "", $4); print $3 ", "  $4}'")
                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Anyone know how to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thanks.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and copy&paste the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the argument of `subprocess.getoutput()` in

```
printers = subprocess.getoutput("lpstat -v | awk '{sub(":", "", $3) sub("ipp://", "", $4) sub("/ipp/print", "", $4); print $3 ", "  $4}'")
```

every double quote begins or ends a string resulting in a string followed by a colon.

`"lpstat -v | awk '{sub("` `:` `", "` `", $3) sub("` `ipp://` `", "` `", $4) sub("` `/ipp/print` `", "` `", $4); print $3 "` `,`  `"  $4}'"`

You have to escape all double quotes inside the string.

```
printers = subprocess.getoutput("lpstat -v | awk '{sub(\":\", \"\", $3) sub(\"ipp://\", \"\", $4) sub(\"/ipp/print\", \"\", $4); print $3 \", \"  $4}'")
```

If you replace the outer double quotes with single quotes you only have to escape the two single quotes.

```
printers = subprocess.getoutput('lpstat -v | awk \'{sub(":", "", $3) sub("ipp://", "", $4) sub("/ipp/print", "", $4); print $3 ", "  $4}\'')
```

See also the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76513947/10622916) for a solution that uses multiline strings enclosed in triple quotes to avoid the need to escape quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer as well as the detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, the quotes are the problem. Python matches closest unescaped matching quote as closing:

```py
t1 = "ab"cd'ef" # wrong syntax, adding this to fix syntax highlight on SO -> '
t2 = "ab\"cd'ef" # ok
t3 = 'ab"cd'ef' # wrong syntax, adding this to fix syntax highlight on SO -> '
t4 = 'ab"cd\'ef' # ok, t2 == t4
```

This becomes annoying at some point, but simple single and double quotes are not the only way to write python strings - you could use the power of multiline strings in the same line! Multiline strings are made by using triple of the same quote character, so single character in the string's body doesn't break it!

```py
t5 = '''ab"cd'ef''' # works, t2 == t5
t6 = """ab"cd'ef""" # works, t2 == t6
```

So you can just do

```py
printers = subprocess.getoutput("""lpstat -v | awk '{sub(":", "", $3) sub("ipp://", "", $4) sub("/ipp/print", "", $4); print $3 ", "  $4}'""")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer here - very useful - I didn't now about the triple quotes!